# Making transparent the unused layout from an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Except my main activity, I need all my remaining activities not being fullsized. So on each `onCreate` I run the following snippet:

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.height = (int) (size.y * 0.6);  
params.width = (int) (size.x * 0.9);
```

This works right, Activity window is resized and centered in the screen, so now I have this activity on top and the main activity (which started this second) in background - but even this one is smaller in size, the remaining unused screen layout is totally opaque.

My goal is to make the unused space by the second window transparent, or at least blurred, I know this is made with the `setAlpha` property, but I can't figure out how to set it to that unused layout of my second activity.

Visually, I mean this effect:

[image: Transparent background]

How to do that? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below theme to the second Activity in manifest.xml file:

```
<style name="TransparentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
<activity
        android:name="second Activity"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentTheme" >
</activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Probably this is the closest approach to what I want that I have tried. You gave me the idea of using that code to replace the `parent` to `@style/AppStyle` (the default style of my app) and setting those `items` makes the effect I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a `Dialog` style to your `Activity`s you should get the effect you're looking for with much less hassle.

Comment: I've tried that also, but it's much more elegant to me the layout for the default theme as the one of the Dialog theme (I'm using `EditText`s and so). I know I could extend it but that's exactly what I want to avoid, I like that theme!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:Theme.Dialog` style to your activity.

Change it in **manifest.xml** file :

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

**Or** programmatically in **activity file**:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Large);
```